# create pie chart with query in php + codeigniter

Tags: php, api, charts, pie-chart

My databse has a table with a column called 'status' where has some 'pendent', 'aprroved', 'waiting' values.
I want to make a pie chart using chart of google chart api.
But I only get this making three queries, one with "where status == 'pendent'",  "where status == 'waiting'",  "where status == 'aprroved'"

Is it possible get this with only one query, to a best performance of database?
What's best way to do this done?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
switch(status){

    case "pendent" :
       //code her
       break;

    case "waiting" :
       //code her
       break;

    case "approved" :
       //code her
         break;
```

Comment: how I get the total number of query these switch cases? With only a query.